# Cordova workflow structure

Tags: cordova

I'm using the *www* folder for all the ionic/angular work, so it includes a lot of files i do not want to end on my actual device, things like:

- the uncompressed js files
- the npm libraries, thats a lot of files
- the un-concatenated css files

What im doing right now is using a hook to delete all the unnecessary files on each build, but was wondering if someone is doing it in a more neater way, as most of the files are copied on each build and then deleted (like the lib or unminified js folder).

Comment: I feel hooks is the solution which is you are using anyhow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the best way is how Ionic 2 is doing it:

1. Create an `app` folder with all the javascript/css/fonts/images files underneath
2. Create a gulp file that concat the js/templates and minify
   everything and copies the result under the `www` folder. So ideally
   the www folder would only contain, the app.js, the app.css, the
   index.html, and a bunch of other assets folder like the fonts/img
   folder.
3. From my experience, `gulp` was far more reliable that using hooks, at
   least for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have my project with me at the moment, but I will share with you my setup with AngularJS in Cordova, which I found is pretty easy to use.

Under the `www` folder, I put all the resources the app needs: fonts, css, partials, scripts (this folder only contains bundled scripts).

Outside the `www` folder (on the same level), I have `bower_modules`, `node_modules`, which will contain the external modules. Additionally, another folder `scripts` which contain TypeScript files I write custom for my app.

Underneath all these folders, a gulpfile picksup all the distribution scripts (the script files that you actually use) from your bower/npm packages and bundles them, then outputs them to `all.min.js` **inside** `www/scripts`.

The `tsconfig` file is setup to output the compiled TypeScript to `www/scripts/bundle.min.js`. The mapping file will be outputted to the same directory for ease of debugging.

In your `index.html`, you will simply reference `all.min.js` followed by `bundle.min.js`.

With this setup, you only include files you need.

(The CSS inclusions follow a similar rule: gulp will bundle css, and output them inside `www/css`.)

Comment: I use almost exactly the same setup. Good answer